# Arrays Simplexml accessing attributes different ways

Tags: php, arrays, attributes, simplexml

Sorry, if I missed the answer here, but I really couldn't find it between all the attribute-questions.

I used SimpleXML to parse an rss-feed and that works great in dev (xampp)

var_dump:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[672]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'A name' (length=11)
      'description' => string 'A very long desc' (length=12)
```

That worked well for me on dev:

```
$desc = (string) $xml->attributes()['description'];
```

...but not on my web-server. I found a solution, that works in both cases:

```
$v = 'description';
$desc = (string) $xml->attributes()->$v;
```

Can someone please tell me why. Is this version-related?
Again: Sorry the question has been asked before.

Edit:
I just found out, that this works also:

```
$a = $xml->attributes();
$desc = (string) $a['description'];
```

Same question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SimpleXML directly – accessing an element inside an *array that is returned by a function* by using `functioncall()['key']` is only possible since PHP version 5.4.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php:

> *“As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.”*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it was something easy. What was new to me was, that I was using php5.4 in dev!
:-)

I updated tags and title and added 'arrays'